# Applescript: "Expected end of line but found identifier"

Tags: applescript

I've got some AppleScript code in a short script someone asked me to edit:

```
repeat with i from 1 to nDirs
    set impf to folder i of importFolder
    my convertFolder(impf,exportFolder,userValue)
end repeat
```

Whenever I try to save it or compile it, though, the AppleScript editor tells me "Syntax error: expected end of line but found identifier" while pointing to the little 'i'.  Is my syntax for the binding of impf incorrect?  How can I get this script compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Change `folder` to `item`.

I'm assuming you want to only "convert" folders, so add "error-checking" (in this case, folder-checking) before calling `convertFolder`...

```
if (impf as string) ends with ":" then my convertFolder(impg, exportFolder, uservalue)
--Alias references ending with a ':' indicate that the item is a folder
```

Comment: OK, but I had already set nDirs to the number of directories only.  So won't this undercount since it examines all the items in the folder rather than just directories?

Comment: @user1080700 No...? Did you look at the script and the comment? I added folder/directory-checking in it so you should be good.